# foreach loop not inserting values into mysql

Tags: php

I have foreach loop that fails to insert data into the db. If I take the insert statement out of the loop it works fine but only for 1 item. Also the echo is returning no data. I would be grateful if someone could check my code and point out my error.

Assume all connections are established and al $_POST values are correct. Many thanks

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/lsorg/users/Connections/ls.php');

    $company = strtoupper(mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_SESSION['ls_idcode_usr']));
    $activity = "Box Return";
    $address = ucwords(mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['address']));
    $service = ucwords(mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['service']));
    $success = 'SUCCESS';
    $authorised = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_SESSION['ls_name_usr']);
    $dept = strtoupper(mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['dept']));
    $boxitems = $_POST['sub'];
    $box = implode(",",$boxitems);
    $array = array();
    $array = $boxitems;


    foreach ($array as $boxes) {
        $outString .= "$box" . "  ";

        //$boxitem = $box;

        $sql = "INSERT INTO act 
                        (service, activity, department, 
                         company, address, user, 
                        `date`, item, new) 
                VALUES ('".$service."', '".$activity."', '".$dept."', 
                        '".$company."', '".$address."', '".$authorised."', 
                        NOW(), '".$boxes."', '1')";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die ('Error inserting box:' . mysqli_error());


    }
    echo $outString;
    mysqli_close($conn); // Connection Closed
?>
```

After adding debug code

> Warning: implode() [function.implode]: Invalid arguments passed in C:\wamp\www\lsorg\users\brtn.php on line 16 Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\wamp\www\lsorg\users\brtn.php on line 22 string(10) "DEMOBOX050" Notice: Undefined variable: outString in C:\wamp\www\lsorg\users\brtn.php on line 39

Reply to what is in `$_POST['sub']`

```
DEMOBOX044,DEMOBOX050
```

Comment: `$array = array();
$array = $boxitems;` And this line is? It only contains `$_POST['sub'];` are you sure, that's an array?

Comment: This should be generating an error `mysqli_error()` !!!! Use `mysqli_error($conn);` and then the script will compile

Comment: For furture code testing Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`
 to the top of your script. This will force any mysqli_ errors to generate an Exception that you can see on the browser and 
 other errors will also be visible on your browser.

Comment: According to him, the mysql works, it's the loop not running. Maybe `var_dump($array);?`

Comment: What is passed in `$_POST['sub']`

Comment: @RiggsFolly i have added `$conn` to mysqli_error() and no errors are reported or data inserted.  result of var_dump($array) string(10) "DEMOBOX050" which is correct as there is only 1 item.Thanks

Comment: Did you also add the debug code I suggested in the previous comment

Comment: @RiggsFolly here is the result after adding erro reporting: `Warning: implode() [function.implode]: Invalid arguments passed in C:\wamp\www\lsorg\users\brtn.php on line 16

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\wamp\www\lsorg\users\brtn.php on line 22
string(10) "DEMOBOX050"
Notice: Undefined variable: outString in C:\wamp\www\lsorg\users\brtn.php on line 39`

Comment: echo the sql variable inside foreach loop and check what query is being executed

Comment: @Bhavik nothing is returned. thanks

Comment: print $_POST['sub'] and post your output

Comment: Change ```$array = $boxitems;``` to ```$array = $box;```. Your $array now = $boxItems = string from post..

Comment: `$array = array(); $array = $boxitems;` won't make `$array` an array. if `$boxitems` is a string, `$array` will be a string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your variables are incorrect.

**Edited to @RiggsFolly's keen eye! (implode -> explode)**

See code:

```
// OLD: $boxitems = implode(",", $_POST['sub']);
$boxitems = explode(",", $_POST['sub']);

foreach ($boxitems as $box) {
  $outString .= "$box" . "  ";
  ...
```

No need for all this..

```
$boxitems = $_POST['sub'];
$box = implode(",",$boxitems);
$array = array();
$array = $boxitems;
```

Comment: Still the same error as posted in comment to @RiggsFolly. thanks

Comment: So your loop isn't triggered. What value does your ```$_POST['sub']``` have?

Comment: DEMOBOX044,DEMOBOX050

Comment: Did your query actually execute after the changes? Because your outString had the wrong value, but your query might have executed.

Comment: So its not an array its a comma delimited string. `implode` is wrong. I think you want `explode()`

Comment: @BertMaurau Not surprising really mate :) The question gave no clue as to what that var contained. Sometimes getting all the info one requires can be like pulling teeth

Comment: @RiggsFolly Just change that t th same time you suggested. works a treat. If you would like to change to an answer i will gladly accept it. Many thanks

Comment: No accept @BertMaurau answer. No point in repeating the same answer